# Does binomial pmf converge uniformly to Poisson pmf?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

Fix $\lambda>0$, and let $p_{\lambda}:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ be the probability mass function (pmf) of Poisson distribution:
\begin{align}
p_{\lambda}(k)=\frac{\lambda^ke^{-\lambda}}{k!},\qquad\forall k\in\mathbb{N}
\end{align}
It is well known that Poisson distribution can be derived as the limit of Binomial distribution (with parameters $n$ and $p$) as $n$ becomes large and $np$ approaches a finite limit, a fact known as the *Poisson limit theorem* or the *Law of rare events*. One version of this says that with $np=\lambda$, the binomial distribution converges to the Poisson distribution as $n\to\infty$. More specifically, denote the pmf of binomial distribution with parameter $n$ by $p_n:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$, given by
\begin{align}
p_n(k)&=\begin{pmatrix}n \\ k\end{pmatrix}p^k(1-p)^{n-k} \\
&=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\left(\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^k\left(1-\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^{n-k},\qquad\forall 0\leq k\leq n
\end{align}
(and $p_n(k)=0$ for all $k>n$). Then the theorem says that $\forall k\in\mathbb{N}$,
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}p_n(k)=p_{\lambda}(k)
\end{align}

---

In this post I am concerned with the **question** of whether the convergence is *uniform*. In terms of the notations set up above:

> Is it true that $p_n$ converges to $p_{\lambda}$ *uniformly* on the whole domain $\mathbb{N}$ as $n\to\infty$? That is, does it hold that
> \begin{align}
> \lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\left|p_n(k)-p_{\lambda}(k)\right|=0?
> \end{align}

---

A simply google search (with keywords like *binomial*, *Poisson*, *uniform convergence*) seems to be futile to get something useful, perhaps this question is not that interesting from the point of view of probability theory? Or maybe I searched it without the correct keywords? In any case, it seems a natural question to ask from the simple point of view of analysis.

Any comment, suggestion or answer are welcome and appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the uniform convergence holds.
In fact, a stronger conclusion is true: we have convergence in total variation distance, i.e. for $n \to \infty$
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} |p_n(k) - p_{\lambda}(k)| \to 0.
$$
This is a consequence of [Le Cam's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Cam%27s_theorem).

Comment: Thanks, it's definitely helpful to know this. May I, however, ask if there is any proof that is more direct/elementary and avoid the use of big tools like Le Cam's theorem? The theorem and notions like convergence in TVD seem to be advanced topics in probability theory. Having had a brief look at Le Cam's papers, it also seems he proved the result using quite advanced tools...